# I'm trying to format "Time(+1:00)" column using datetime method to group the values on date and hour basis , but I'm getting following error ;

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, datetime-format

data :

```
       Date    Time(+01:00) Friction State  Ta  Tsurf   Water   Height
0   2021.02.16  07:11:19    0.33    6   -2.4    -6.07   0   118
1   2021.02.16  07:11:20    0.33    6   -2.4    -6.12   0   118
2   2021.02.16  07:11:21    0.33    6   -2.4    -6.17   0   118
3   2021.02.16  07:11:22    0.34    6   -2.4    -6.16   0   118
4   2021.02.16  07:11:23    0.33    6   -2.4    -6.34   0   118
```

code :

```
df['Time(+01:00)'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Time(+01:00)'], format='%H:%M:%S').dt.hour
df = df.groupby(['Date','Time(+01:00)']).mean()
df = df.drop_duplicates()
df.head()
```

error:

```
pandas\_libs\tslibs\strptime.pyx in pandas._libs.tslibs.strptime.array_strptime()

ValueError: time data 'Time(+01:00)' does not match format '%H:%M:%S' (match)
```

-> The time is in 24-hour format .

Comment: You probably need to strip your column

Comment: Looks like your time column contains string 'Time(+01:00)', which you try to parse with %H:%M:%S (which obviously doesn't work).

Comment: Yes ,The data had some string values in them . finally resolved . Thanks a lot.